# SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES for Spark 2.2.0

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark 2.2.0, I do not see the option SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES to launch multiple workers per node. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `spark-env.sh` file inside `conf` directory of `spark` folder, you will see an option `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1`. You can change it to the number you want.

So when spark is started with `sbin/start-all.sh` then number of worker nodes defined should be started on that machine.

Comment: Thanks. I found it. it is missing from the online documentation.  I hope I can use the option with spark-submit as --conf key=value format as I dont have the permission to change the spark-env.sh file.

Comment: Nope . there should not be such configuration in spark. You can try though. If successful let me know too :)

Comment: Just for clarification, will spark.executor.instances=3 will launch multiple workers per node?

Comment: To be honest I haven't tried that myself. I have tried the answer way though which i am afraid you are not authorized

Answer (score 0):

According to Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts):

> To launch a Spark standalone cluster with the launch scripts, you should create a file called conf/slaves in your Spark directory, which must contain the hostnames of all the machines where you intend to start Spark workers, one per line. If conf/slaves does not exist, the launch scripts defaults to a single machine (localhost), which is useful for testing